# Abstract value in a csv cell using Regex in python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I am abstracting a number value from a csv column like:

```
column=[None, you earn 5%]
```

It would be great if it can store 'None' as 0 and simply 5% for the second one.

I tried to transfer the % with the following code. But it raise error as

> "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

```
data.loc[(data['column'] == re.findall(r'([\w]+)', data['column'])), 'disc'] = re.findall(r'([0-9]+\%)',data['column'])
```

And for loop. But doesn't seemed helpful

```
def fs(a):
    for i in a:
        if i == 'None':
            a[i] = 0
        else:
            a[i]=re.search(r'(?<=\().+?(?=\))', a[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Data Frame that has a string column and you want to replace the string 'None" by 0 and also keep numbers and % then do:

```
df.textColumn.str.replace("None","0").str.replace("[^0-9.%]", "")
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'n':[1,2,3,4], 'text':["None","you earn 5%", "this is 3.4%", "5.5"]})

df['text'] = df.text.str.replace("None","0").str.replace("[^0-9.%]", "")

df

n   text
0   1   0
1   2   5%
2   3   3.4%
3   4   5.5
```